# How can I display a website (e.g. apple) in a cocoa app using WebKit?

Tags: macos, webkit

Ok guys, so far I've coded the whole thing by following other people's answers however when I build and run my project the website or html files I specify in the code don't display on the screen; no more than a white screen is displayed.

This is what I've done so far on my header file:

```
//MY HEADER FILE(.h):

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface Project_XAppDelegate: NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSWindow *window;
IBOutlet WebView *webView;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *webView;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
//MY IMPLEMENTATION FILE(.m):

#import "Project_XAppDelegate.h"
#import "WebKit/Webkit.h"

@implementation Project_XAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize webView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Users/*****/Desktop/Project X/HTML/mehmar.html"];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your htmlPath looks wrong to me. Not too familiar with OSX development, but once you get the bundle path shouldn't you just append "index.html" to it instead of the complete path to your file on disk.

Try `[resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"index.html"]` ?

Comment: thanks for the advice Tejaswi but I did work it out beforehand, however; do you know how to display a web URL? What I mean is the same principle of displaying a website however in this case having the app linked to the web page so that it is up-to date when it is accessed. Thanks!